# Regex in a window-slide esq possible?

Tags: regex, pad

I am wondering if it is possible to use regex to split/replace a string and pad the matches with following n characters?

For example, my use case would be to parse strings in window-slide esque way:

with n = 3

`"abcdef".split("..")`

becomes

`["abc", "bcd", "cde", "def"]`

or in the case of replace,

`"abcdef".replace("..")`

becomes

`"abcbcdcdedef"`

Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible because regex cannot go back. You can search from some point by looking ahead but you must consume it forward to get result. For example you can get `a` followed by `bc` with `a(?=bc)` but you only get `a` because you only consumed `a`, so next search will start from after `a` not after `c`. And if you get result of `abc` already by using `abc`, you cannot go back to `b` to get `bcd` because regex does not support backward consumption.

Comment: And in case of split, rule is same. If you already get `abc` by some way, your start point is already moved to after `c`, so you cannot get `bcd` because you cannot move back your start point.